# Typescript build with --watch extremely slow when using `declaration: true`

Tags: typescript, tsc

I have been experimenting with using declaration maps to improve editor performance and have found that enabling `declaration: true` causes extremely slow builds when using the `--watch` flag with `tsc`.

Previous to enabling `declaration: true`, files would rebuild quickly on save, but after enabling the setting, I'm finding the build with `--watch` takes almost as long to build when saving one file as if I were building from scratch, even if I'm modifying a file that has no imports or files that import it.

I've used the `-generateTrace` flag to investigate the difference between the two builds and have come to the conclusion that tsc seems to be type checking and re-emitting d.ts files for most of my codebase every time a file is saved, even if the files aren't related to the changed file.

Here is an example of a performance trace prior to enabling `declaration: true`:
[image]

And here is one for exactly the same trigger for the watch command, except after enabling `declaration: true`:
[image]

I get that I can expect the second to be a bit slower because of the extra d.ts file that has to be generated, but I was not expecting tsc to start recompiling unrelated files as well.

Is there a way to get this to build quicker? If anyone can point out what I'm missing here, I'd be very grateful.

Update: I've now bumped my typescript version to the latest, and the build is certainly a bit faster with `declaration: true` than it was before, but it is still building all the files

Comment: Have you tried enabling `incremental` compilation from `tsconfig.json`? That might solve the issue.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make any difference whether `--incremental` is true or false

Comment: Interesting.. I wonder what is the actual issue here...